# setText() doesn't work after Activity change

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I have button with `setText()` to `TextView`. When I click it the text changes. Next, I change activity to another and back to main activity. Now `setText()` doesn't work (text isn't replaced).

My code:

```
public void test(View view) {
    String dataS = "dupa slonia";
    data.setText(dataS);
    System.out.println(dataS);
}
```

Comment: `String` object don't have `setText` method, i think you want `TextView`. please read documentation first

Comment: Post your activity class please.

Comment: I use setText to TextView object ;) data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

Comment: It seems that `data` is null after returning to the `MainActivity`

Comment: I have data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); in onCreate()

Comment: try putting it in `onResume()`

Comment: If data would be null then should throw NPE. It would be easier if you could post your `MainActivity`

Comment: My MainActivity: http://pastebin.com/sxVnvFGt I have all methods in MainActivity class beacouse if I put it in other class I have crash

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onBackPressed()` in the function which executes when button is clicked for going back to *MainActivity.java*

Answer (score 0):

When you back to an `Activity`, you don't pass by the OnCreate method.

You have to put your code on the `OnResume()` method.

Take a look to the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).